# Image Posting is failing with Type Encoding Issue

Tags: afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am trying to upload a picture from an iPhone to a *Django Web Service* and I keep getting a *400* with this specific message :

`error: {"image": ["No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on the form."]}`.

I have sat up for hours trying to figure this out and i believe that somehow, the mime-type is not being sent properly.

Would you have any ideas, or better ways to upload an image than my code below :

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://MYADDRESS"]];
[manager setRequestSerializer:[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]];
[manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:@"user" password:@"pass"];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"image" : imageData, @"name" : @"MyImage" ,  @"Content-Type" : @"image/jpeg"};
AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager POST:@"/api/photo/" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"MyImage" fileName:@"MyImage.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
}];
[op setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {

    NSLog(@"%f%% Uploaded", round(((float)totalBytesWritten / (float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite) * 100.));

}];
[op start];
```